# inspected target disconnected angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a little Quiz App in Angular.js. 
I use a ng-click function for testing if the answer I choose is right or wrong using a JSON document. When i'm clicking on anwser and decide to change that (true to false, or false to true) I got an inspected target disconnected from Google Chrome.

I tried to use a Google Chrome without any Extension.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quizApp" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/quizCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('quizApp', ['ngRoute'])

angular.module('quizApp').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    var routes = [
        {
            url: '/home',
            template: 'templates/quiz.html',
            controller: 'quizCtrl'
        }
    ];

    routes.forEach(function(r, index) {
        $routeProvider.when(r.url, { templateUrl: r.template, controller: r.controller});
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : '/home' });
}]);
```

quizCtrl.js

```
app.controller('quizCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.responses = 
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : './data/quiz.json'
        }).then(function successCallBack(data) {
            $scope.datas = data.data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
    $scope.result = []; 
    $scope.isTrue = function(response) {
        $scope.json = angular.fromJson(response);
        if ($scope.result.length == 0) {
            if($scope.json.isTrue) {
                        $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, false);
                    }   
        }
        else {
            console.log($scope.result.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.result.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.result[i] == $scope.json.id) {
                    $scope.result.splice(i, 2);
                    if($scope.json.isTrue) {
                            $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, true);
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, false);
                        }
                }
                else {
                    if ($scope.result[i] == true || $scope.result[i] == false) {
                        console.log("do nothing " + i);
                    }
                    else {
                        if($scope.json.isTrue) {
                            $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, true);
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, false);
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log($scope.result);
    }
});
```

I believe the bug in my code should be in this part of the code (because it crash just after the line 23 in the quizCtrl.js

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.result.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.result[i] == $scope.json.id) {
        $scope.result.splice(i, 2);
        if($scope.json.isTrue) {
            $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, true);
        }
        else {
            $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, false);
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($scope.result[i] == true || $scope.result[i] == false) {              
             console.log("do nothing " + i);
        }
        else {
            if($scope.json.isTrue) {
                $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, true);
            }
            else {
                $scope.result.push($scope.json.id, false);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your specific issue is that you're iterating over the result using`$scope.result.length` and then within the loop you're pushing on to that array.  If you comment out the 4 lines within the for loop that push on to the array it doesn't break.  So I think pushing on to the result array that your iterating over is causing the issue.

[This](http://howdoididit.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/inspected-target-disconnected-error-fix.html) might help you.

The "Inspected error disconnected error" occurs when you are developing some webpage or some CORS request via the browser and either the file you try to access is too large for the browser to handle or the plugins interfere with our program ( the one we are eveloping).

Solution : 
Try to disable all the plugins or the ones that involve allowing CORS or disable ones which provide same functionality ( e.g. you may have 2-3 plugins doing same job of allowing CORS which may interfere).
Check the file you are accessing ( of course, you can check out the file only if you are developing some web service, app or some web development so that the file will be there locally).

Comment: I'm using WAMP to use ng-route in my local project. Is that what you are talking about ?

Comment: WAMP should't make a difference, do you have a plunkr example?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uxHHguOUw58NNsq8oQkG?p=preview is that what you need ? Never done one before

Comment: Yeah that helped, I could reproduce it.  I've updated my answer, hope it helps!